# Play Framework 2.x Ebean query ManyToMany for all

Tags: java, orm, playframework-2.0, ebean

I have two models in Play Framework 2/Ebean, 'Article' and 'Tag', which has a ManyToMany-relationship to each other.

Article:

```
@Entity   
public class Article extends Model {

@ManyToMany
List<Tag> tags;

// ...

}
```

Tag:

```
@Entity   
public class Tag extends Model {

@ManyToMany
List<Article> articles;

// ...

}
```

Given a `List<Tag>`, how do i write a query for Articles that contains **All** of the tags in the list?

I am aware that I can use `Article.find().where().in("tags", tags)` to find all Articles that contains **Any** of the tags in the list, but I'm looking to be more specific

Comment: Have you tried to approach the problem from other perspective and use a SQL query to fetch this information?

Comment: Nope, I have been saving that as the last option if all else fails :) But it is beginning to seem like it might be the only option. I was hoping that there was some obvious way to achieve this through Ebean that I was missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use a RawSql query; once you start joining and adding lots of clauses, things get out of hand pretty quickly. At that point it gets really easy to write a query that's hard to debug and even harder to modify in the future. In the end, your query still gets turned into an SQL query, and you aren't saving yourself much aside from satisfying curiosity to see if it can be done.

Set a String `sql=`

```
SELECT a.id 
  FROM ARTICLE_TAG a
    JOIN TAG t ON t.id = a.tag_id
  WHERE t.name IN ( :tags )
  GROUP BY a.id
  HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT t.name) = :num_tags
```

And then do this:

```
RawSql rawSql =
  RawSqlBuilder
    .parse(sql)
    .columnMapping("a.id", "id")
    .create();

List<Article> articles = Ebean.find(Article.class)
  .setRawSql(rawSql)
  .setParameter("tags", tags)
  .setParameter("num_tags", tags.length)
  .findList();
```

Comment: Very good answer! You could almost argue that even if there *was* a way to do this with only Ebean, a RawSql query would be prefered because much easier to read an debug. Thank you!